# NoSuchElementException while executing my testscript

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Observing following error while executing my test script. Can someone help me in identifying the cause of failure.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"lid"}
Command duration or timeout: 20.45 seconds
```

Here is the snippet of my code. Please note that the element exist in same frame hence frame switch is not needed.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginPage 
{
    @Test
    public void testLoginFail()
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/crm/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("LOGIN")).click();
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("lid"))));
        driver.findElement(By.id("lid")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
```

HTML view of the element is:

```
<input name="lid" id="lid" class="input usrbx" value="" onkeypress="clearmsg()" type="email">
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping `driver.findElement(By.id("lid")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");` statement in a `explicit wait`? Also attach the login form HTML else, people will have a hard time helping you. What I would do is open the browser console and trying to see what selector fills the input with `.val()`. (e.g.: `$('#lid').val("xyz@gmail.com")`). If it works with console JQuery, it will work with your selectors. :)

Comment: I have already tried wrapping this statement with explicit wait, but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Dks have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inspected the webpage "https://www.zoho.com/crm/lp/login.html" and i am able to see an iframe in it and the input text boxes are inside it. Below is the working code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\Web Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();


    driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/crm/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("LOGIN")).click();

    //Switch to the frame
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    driver.findElement(By.id("lid")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for favour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

A few words about the Solution:

1. While working with Selenium 3.4.0 with geckodriver v0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox 53.0 you need to download the latest geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and provide the absolute path of the geckodriver through `System.setProperty`.
2. Try to avoid `implicitlyWait` as per recent updates `implicitlyWait` may die in fire soon.
3. The error you are seeing `NoSuchElementException` says it all. The `id` of the element is not traceable.
4. The element with id `lid` is within an iframe, so you need to switch to frame first.
5. Here is your own code with some simple tweaks in it:

   ```
   @Test
   public void testLoginFail()
   {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/crm/");
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.findElement(By.linkText("LOGIN")).click();
       driver.switchTo().frame("zohoiam");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lid']")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");


   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: yes,i used my code by switching to frame, now it is working. Thanks